# tflite SSD-MobileNet_V2 Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 320 but expected 1 for dimension 1 of input 0

Tags: tensorflow-lite

Could anyone be so kind to give me some help?

I was trying to do some experiment with tflite as beginner for object detection.
I downloaded sample model from Tensorflow website for tflite mode ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_100/fp32

https://tfhub.dev/iree/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_100/fp32/default/1

then I run my code as below

> interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path='lite-
> model_ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_100_fp32_default_1.tflite')
> interpreter.allocate_tensors()
>
> input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
> output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
> img = Image.open('table.jpeg') img = img.resize((320,320))
>
> input_data = (np.float32(img) - 127.5) / 127.5 input_data =
> np.expand_dims(img, axis=0).astype(np.float32)

then I get a input tensor with shape of (1,320,320,3). then comes problem when feeding to model

> interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

then I got below message

> ---

ValueError Traceback (most recent callast)  in ()

> ----> 1 interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py
> in set_tensor(self, tensor_index, value)
> 695       ValueError: If the interpreter could not set the tensor.
> 696     """
> --> 697     self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
> 698
> 699   def resize_tensor_input(self, input_index, tensor_size, strict=False):
>
> **ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 320 but expected 1 for dimension 1 of input 0.**

so it should mean the input tensor somehow violate some rules.

then I checked the input details by

> input_details

then I find the shape of input array is defined for shape (1,1,1,3)

> [{'dtype': numpy.float32,   'index': 0,   'name':
> 'normalized_input_image_tensor',   'quantization': (0.0, 0),
> 'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,    'scales':
> array([], dtype=float32),    'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
> **'shape': array([1, 1, 1, 3], dtype=int32),**   'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1,  3], dtype=int32),   'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

but when I check the description of the model on Tensorflow website

> normalized_input_image_tensor: an uint8 array of shape [batch, height,
> width, channels] where batch = 1, channels = 3, and height and width
> can be any size. Values should be normalized to [-1, 1].

so basically there is no requirement on the shape of dimension 1 and dimension 2 or input tensor.

how should I solve this problem?

I tried models which already defined for (1,320,320,3). at least it can run without error.

much thanks for your great help!

regards

Cliff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the model works with variable sizes, the input size needs to be set explicitly using the method [resize_tensor_input()](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#resize_tensor_input).

Comment: Hi, Mariewhite! Thanks a lot! I will try and let you know if it works! :)

Comment: Hio Mariewhite, yes my code runs.  there is no error again. but I am still trying to understand the raw output and how to decode them....  but anyway, it works.  thanks very much!